# attempt to index globall 'city1' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My code.............

```
local physics = require"physics" ---- 
physics.start()
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
```

---

```
function scene:enterScene(event)
    city1.enterFrame= scrollCity
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",city1)

    city2.enterFrame= scrollCity
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",city2)

    city3.enterFrame= scrollCity
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",city3)

    city4.enterFrame= scrollCity
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",city4)

    Runtime:addEventListener("touch",touchScreen)
end

scene:addEventListener("enterScene",scene)
 return scene
```

but Corona Error

```
game.lua:65: attempt to index globall 'city1' (a nil value)
```

Comment: You didn't show where is `city1` defined.

Comment: local city1 = display.newImage("city1.png")
    city1:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
    city1.x=0
    city1.y=320
    city1.speed=1

Comment: when i delete function scene:enterScene(event)
 it normal operation\

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple. You're defining `city1` as local variable. In the function `scene:enterScene(event)` it doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a scope issue. First, you should declare things local. When you leave off the local you make a global and that will get you into more trouble than it solves. Instead you should learn about scope in programming. In Storyboard and Composer you have to declare variables you want to access in multiple functions at a higher level. This tutorial explains it all:

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/06/16/tutorial-scope-for-beginners/